# how to output multiple bundles with browserify and gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, browserify

I have browserify bundling up files and it's working great. But what if I need to generate multiple bundles?

I would like to end up with `dist/appBundle.js` and `dist/publicBundle.js`

```
gulp.task("js", function(){

    return browserify([
            "./js/app.js",
            "./js/public.js"
        ])
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source("bundle.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));

});
```

Obviously this isn't going to work since I am only specifying one output (bundle.js). I can accomplish this by repeating the above statement like so (but it doesn't feel right, because of the repetition):

```
gulp.task("js", function(){

    browserify([
            "./js/app.js"
        ])
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source("appBundle.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));


    browserify([
            "./js/public.js"
        ])
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source("publicBundle.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));

});
```

Is there a better way to tackle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't have a good environment to test this in right now, but my guess is that it would look something like:

```
gulp.task("js", function(){
    var destDir = "./dist";

    return browserify([
        "./js/app.js",
        "./js/public.js"
    ])
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source("appBundle.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir))
        .pipe(rename("publicBundle.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir));

});
```

EDIT: I just realized I mis-read the question, there should be two separate bundles coming from two separate .js files. In light of that, the best alternative I can think of looks like:

```
gulp.task("js", function(){
    var destDir = "./dist";

    var bundleThis = function(srcArray) {
        _.each(srcArray, function(source) {
            var bundle = browserify(["./js/" + source + ".js"]).bundle();
            bundle.pipe(source(source + "Bundle.js"))
                  .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir));
        });
    };

    bundleThis(["app", "public"]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think in your example though the public.js file is never pulled in and "browserified," unless I'm missing something.

Comment: ah - I think I had originally mis-read your question. Let me see if I can come up with a better alternative...

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes I forget it's just js (when I dive into the node world). I'll give it a try

Comment: yeah the same thing happens to me - I get so caught up in frameworks and other people's code samples. It doesn't help that so much these days seems to happen automagically

Comment: I'm using `babelify` as well... I keep getting the error: `Did you forget to signal async completion?`

Answer (score 4):

```js
gulp.task("js", function (done) {
  [
    "app",
    "public",
  ].forEach(function (entry, i, entries) {
    // Count remaining bundling operations to track
    // when to call done(). Could alternatively use
    // merge-stream and return its output.
    entries.remaining = entries.remaining || entries.length;

    browserify('./js/' + entry + '.js')
      .bundle()
      // If you need to use gulp plugins after bundling then you can
      // pipe to vinyl-source-stream then gulp.dest() here instead
      .pipe(
        require('fs').createWriteStream('./dist/' + entry + 'Bundle.js')
        .on('finish', function () {
          if (! --entries.remaining) done();
        })
      );
  });
});
```

This is similar to @urban_racoons answer, but with some improvements:

- That answer will fail as soon as you want the task to be a dependency of another task in gulp 3, or part of a series in gulp 4. This answer uses a callback to signal task completion.
- The JS can be simpler and doesn't require underscore.

This answer is based on the premise of having a known list of entry files for each bundle, as opposed to, say, needing to glob a list of entry files.

Answer (score 3):

## Multiple bundles with shared dependencies

I recently added support for multiple bundles with shared dependencies to https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter

Here's the array of browserify [config objects](https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter/blob/master/gulp/config.js#L29-L47) I pass to my [browserify task](https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter/blob/master/gulp/tasks/browserify.js). At the end of that task, I iterate over each config, browserifying all the things.

```
config.bundleConfigs.forEach(browserifyThis);
```

`browserifyThis` takes a bundleConfig object, and runs browserify (with watchify if dev mode).

This is the bit that [sorts out shared dependencies](https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter/blob/master/gulp/tasks/browserify.js#L62-L67):

```
// Sort out shared dependencies.
// b.require exposes modules externally
if(bundleConfig.require) b.require(bundleConfig.require)
// b.external excludes modules from the bundle, and expects
// they'll be available externally
if(bundleConfig.external) b.external(bundleConfig.external)
```

This browserify task also properly [reports when all bundles are finished](https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter/blob/master/gulp/tasks/browserify.js#L70-L85) (the above example isn't returning streams or firing the task's callback), and [uses watchify](https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter/blob/master/gulp/tasks/browserify.js#L55-L60) when in devMode for super fast recompiles.

Brian FitzGerald's last comment is spot on. Remember that it's just JavaScript!

Comment: I noticed your repo moved to Webpack - at this point would you suggest going that direction rather than trying to get multiple bundles to work with Browserify? Trying to figure out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726088/how-do-i-properly-separate-my-app-js-and-vendor-js-bundles-using-browserify