# How to boot a multi-page app with Browserify and Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify, node-modules

Ok, I'm near to the finish line with my new PHP/JS app built with Gulp and Browserify. The last part is how to "boot", I mean how to do the "first call".

Let's say I have 3 JS entry points

```
/js/articles.js
/js/categories.js
/js/comments.js
```

each of them using some JS modules.
Then I have 3 HTML files, requiring their JS

```
/articles.html
/categories.html
/comments.html
```

example /js/articles.js

```
var $ =                 require("jquery");
var common =            require("../common.js");

var viewModel = {

    readData: function() {
        /* read record from API and render */
    },

    insert: function() {
        /* open a modal to insert new record */
    }
};
```

What I should do now is to perform this sort of "boot": that is calling some init function I need, then load server data, then bind all buttons and stuff to viewModel's methods

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    common.init();
    viewModel.readData();
    $('#btn-add').click(viewModel.insert);
});
```

Ok, but where am I to put this?

A) In HTML file?
I can't cause I don't have any global JS variabile to access..

B) Am I put it into articles.js?
At the moment, my Gulp task will bundle everything (articles.js, categories.js, comments.js, common libraries) into a single bundle.js.
If I put it into articles.js it will end up into the bundle.js. So articles-related boot stuff would be called in "categories" page either. And this is wrong.

C) Should I split articles.js into 2 files, one containing viewModel definition and the other doing the $(document).ready stuff?... but again how do I access to the correct viewModel?

Which is the correct solution?

Thank you

Comment: This answer might be able to help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23836379/2661028

Answer (score -1):

Seems your gulp task would just concat all the entries into bundle.js so you probably could just add another entry called `js/index.js` and put your initialization code inside it.

It's confusing that your code will be executed (base on your description in B) even though you don't call require on it. Can you provide your bundle.js and one of your html file?